# make dyanmic scroll using "scrollIntoView" if I will using one class no problem but the problem with the dynamic class

Tags: javascript, scroll, js-scrollintoview

> // html

```
<div class="nav-bullets">
      <div class="bullet">
        <div class="tooltip" data-i=".about-us">About Us</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bullet">
        <div class="tooltip" data-i=".skills">Our Skills</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bullet">
        <div class="tooltip" data-i=".gallery">Our Gallery</div>
      </div>
      <div class="bullet">
        <div class="tooltip" data-i=".timeline">TimeLine</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> // javascript

> using one class no promlem like this

```
// Select All Bullets
const allBullets = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-bullets .bullet");

allBullets.forEach(bullet => {
bullet.addEventListener("click" , (e) => {
    document.querySelector(".about-us").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
 
});
});
```

> // the problem

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')     at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>
```

//  but if i will  make the class dynamic not working  like this

```
 allBullets.forEach(bullet => { bullet.addEventListener("click" , (e) => {     document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.i).scrollIntoView({       behavior: 'smooth'     });   }); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the event listener to the `.bullet` element, but it has no `data-i` attribute, you've added that to the child `.tooltip`:

```
<div class="bullet"> <-- event listener is here
  <div class="tooltip" data-i=".about-us"> <-- data attribute is here
    About Us
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is why `e.target.dataset.i` is undefined and `document.querySelector(undefined)` doesn't match any element.

Move the data attribute to the `.bullet`.